# Firefox Extension: multiple requests with XMLHttpRequest. Use Asynchronous or not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox-addon, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying something very simple for my first Firefox Add-On, the important part is:

Step 1) Call an external API to retrieve some data.
Step 2) Call that API again with the data retrieved the first time to get some more.

Now, I first implemented it using XMLHttpRequest in synchronous mode, since I thought the need to wait for Step 2 forced me to do it that way. Two calls to the function that dealt with the API call, used XMLHttpRequest and parsed the response. Fine.

Then I came accross various docs in the Mozilla Development Network which encourage you to use XMLHttpRequest in asynchronous mode and so I tried.

Basing my implementation on [multiple XMLHttpRequests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203074/firefox-extension-multiple-xmlhttprequest-calls-per-page) and others I came up with the code below.

My question is: Is this the proper way to do it? Should I go back to using synchronous mode? It works like this, but it just doesn't strike me as the correct AJAX pattern you would use...

```
  // first call
  var username = foo;
  var password = bar;
  var startOffset = 0; // initial value
  var url = encodeURIComponent('https://theapiurl.com/query=' + startOffset);
  doRequest();

  function doRequest() {
    makeRequest(url, username, password);
  }

  function makeRequest(url, username, password) {
    var http_request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    if (http_request.overrideMimeType) {
      http_request.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
    }
    if (!http_request) {
      alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
      return false;
    }
    http_request.onreadystatechange = function() { 
       alertContents(http_request);
    };
    http_request.open('GET', url, true, username, password);
    http_request.send(null);
  }  

  function alertContents(http_request) {
    if (http_request.readyState == 4) {
      if (http_request.status == 200) {
        if (startOffset == 0) {
          startOffset = 45; // this value would be extracted from 'http_request'
          url = encodeURIComponent('https://theapiurl.com/query=' + startOffset);
          // second call, parameter startOffset has changed
          doRequest();
        } else {
        }
      } else {
        alert('There was a problem with the request.');
      }
      http_request.onreadystatechange = function fnNull(){};
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always avoid doing synchronous network requests as it will block the GUI from functioning until you get a response.  Just because the network may be fast for you, you should not assume it will be fast for all of your users.

Comment: Fine. I understand that. Now, would you code it like that in my case? I'm mostly interested in the calling of doRequest() from alertContents()

Comment: If the calls are dependent on each other (as in, order is important), yes, that is the way I'd do it.

Comment: If the calls are dependent on each other (as in, order is important), then, you **still** should use asynchronous requests. You just make the second request from the callback function passed to the first request. Such is normal use of asynchronous requests. At this point the use of the [promise interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) might be useful.